# Count occurences of phrases in lowercase sentences without punctuation

Tags: c#, count, frequency, find-occurrences

Example Inputs:

- peter warns pete to not go to the sea
- alfred should go to the sea
- albert warns pete
- i told you to not go to disneyland

Example Outputs:

- 3: go to
- 2: go to the sea
- 2: to not go to

Optional:

- Do not count occurrences below 2.

My approach

```
public void zähleHäufigkeitWorte(string[] arr, int n)
{
    bool[] visited = new bool[n];

    // Traverse through array elements and 
    // count frequencies 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        // Skip this element if already processed 
        if (visited[i] == true)
            continue;

        // Count frequency 
        int count = 1;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                visited[j] = true;
                count++;
            }
        }
        wort.Add(arr[i],count);
    }
}
```

How do I extend to count the occurrences of phrases?

Comment: You might need a `Dictionary<string, int>` where the key is the phrase and the value is the occurrence counter.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SO68666232
{
    public class PhraseCounter
    {

        public static Dictionary<string, int> countWordAndPhraseFrequencies(string input)
        {
            var phraseDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            string[] tokens = input.Split(' ');
            int ntokens = tokens.Length;
            for (int start = 0; start < ntokens; start++)
            {
                for (int nwords = 1; nwords <= (ntokens- start) ; nwords++)
                {
                    ArraySegment<string> phraseTokens = new ArraySegment<string>(tokens, start, nwords);
                    string phrase = string.Join(" ", phraseTokens);
                    if (phraseDic.ContainsKey(phrase))
                    {
                        phraseDic[phrase]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        phraseDic[phrase] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Remove elements with only 1 occurrence
            IEnumerable<string> keys = new List<string>(phraseDic.Keys);
            foreach (string key in keys)
            {
                if (phraseDic[key] <= 1)
                {
                    phraseDic.Remove(key);
                }
            }
            return phraseDic;
        }
    }
}
```

It may not be the most efficient way, as the time increases as number of words squared, but it works.

Test program:

```
    class Program
    {
        const string sampleInput = "peter warns pete to not go to the sea alfred should go to the sea albert warns pete i told you to not go to disneyland";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var res = PhraseCounter.countWordAndPhraseFrequencies(sampleInput);
            foreach (string key in res.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", key, res[key]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Results:

```
warns: 2
warns pete: 2
pete: 2
to: 5
to not: 2
to not go: 2
to not go to: 2
not: 2
not go: 2
not go to: 2
go: 3
go to: 3
go to the: 2
go to the sea: 2
to the: 2
to the sea: 2
the: 2
the sea: 2
sea: 2
```

Comment: Hello. I get a `System.OutOfMemoryException` at `string phrase = string.Join(" ", phraseTokens);`.

Comment: Are you using the test string given here or a larger input? What is the size of your input? The algorithm basically makes a list of every possible phrase, so if you have n words in the input, there will be O(n^2) possible phrases with average length O(n), so the memory requirements increase as O(n^3). The algorithm could be easily modified to respect a maximum phrase length of say 10 words, then the memory requirements would be significantly reduced.

Comment: Another alternative would be to modify the algorithm to count the number of occurrences of the phrase immediately and only save if > 1, instead of accumulating every phrase and filtering at the end.